# Render image sequence in .png with trasparent background in WM

Tags: plotting, graphics

I make the premise that I am a newbie to WM.

I need to render a sequence of 2d graphs in .png format with transparent background, the function depends on two variables that for simplicity I will call "x" and "t", x will be the dependent variable in the xy graph, while t is the one that I have to vary to obtain different images of the sequence.

If I used a programming language I know I would insert the plot function inside a for loop dependent on the t variable, how can I do it on WM?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please visit the documentation for `Plot` and try out a few examples. If you have already tried out Mathematica code and are having difficulty, please include that code in your post and ask a more specific question. The code can be copied directly from your notebook cell and formatted using the braces `{ }`on the edit window.

Comment: Try to check also `Export` in the documentation.